# What does annotate mean at a request rate limiter

Tags: django, rate-limiting

I'm using Django Ratelimit to limit the rate my views can be called by an IP.

But I don't know what the parameter `block` means, [documented here](http://django-ratelimit.readthedocs.org/en/latest/usage.html).

When I set it to True, I get a 403 when my rate limit is exceeded.

But I don't understand what happens when it is set to False. The doc says:

```
block – False Whether to block the request instead of annotating.
```

My question is: What does "annotate" mean in this context.

Comment: As far as I see in the documentation examples, there is a `was_limited = getattr(request, 'limited', False)` example. I believe setting it to False, will not block the request (in the documentation it specified that `block=True` raises an exception, something that does not happen when block is set to `False`, you only get the `limited` attribute within the request object.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As you say, the decorator raises a `Ratelimited` exception when `block=True`. This returns a 403 Permission Denied response to the user.

If `block=False`, no exception is raised. However, a boolean `limited` has been set on the request object. In your view, you can check for this 'annotation' using `getattr`, and handle it however you like.

```
was_limited = getattr(request, 'limited', False):
if was_limited:
    return HttpResponse("You have been rate limited")
```

So if you use `block=False`, it's up to you to check the value `request.limited`, and handle it properly.